# How to avoid repeated ids with ng-repeat + bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I built nested Bootstrap `.collapse` and `ng-repeat`. They have 3 levels: `dists`, `admins`, and `agents`.

In order to make Bootstrap collapse work you need different id's for each `.collapse`. So I added an `$index + 1` to the id's:

```
  <div id="dists" class="list-container">
    <div class="dist" ng-repeat="dist in dists track by $index">
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#admins-{{$index + 1}}" ng-click="updatePanels()">
      </a>
      <div id="admins-{{$index + 1}}" class="list-container collapse">
        <div class="admin" ng-repeat="admin in dist.admins track by $index">
          <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#agents-{{$index + 1}}" ng-click="updatePanels()">
          </a>
          <div id="agents-{{$index + 1}}" class="list-container collapse">
            <div class="agent" ng-repeat="agent in admin.agents track by $index">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It works--except I end up with duplicated ids:

```
.dist
  #admin-1 <- repeated
    #agent-1
    #agent-2

.dist
  #admin-1 <- repeated
```

What's the simplest way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inner loops, you can access the outer `$index` via `$parent.$index`. For example

```
<div id="admins-{{$parent.$index + 1}}-{{$index + 1}}"
```

and for the 3rd level (agents), use `$parent.$parent.$index` to access the *dist* index.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$parent

---

Another option and one that is probably more succinct is to assign the index to a locally scoped property via `ng-init`. For example

```
<div class="dist" ng-repeat="dist in dists track by $index"
    ng-init="distIndex = $index + 1">
    <div id="admins-{{distIndex}}">
        <div class="admin" ng-repeat="admin in dist.admins track by $index"
            ng-init="adminIndex = $index + 1">
            <!-- and so on -->
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way to create one $index for all the loops? That way the index will go like 1,2,3,4 for all and there won't be any repeated ids. I tried this `<div id="dists" class="list-container" ng-init="globalIndex = $index + 1">` `<div id="admins-{{globalIndex}}" ` but I'm still getting the same result as my example above.

Comment: @alexchenco try `globalIndex += $index + 1`

Comment: got this error: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '=' not a primary expression at column 14 of the expression [parentIndex += $index + 1] starting at [= $index + 1].`

Comment: Anyway, I'll try your second solution.

Comment: Ha, the second solution messed up the loop. I didn't imagine this would be so hard.

Comment: Okay, I got it working: `<div class="dist" ng-repeat="dist in dists track by $index" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">` `<div id="admins-{{parentIndex + 1}}-{{$index + 1}}" class="list-container collapse">` Thanks!